# #define sin valor asignado

Tags: c, define

Ando mirando un código ajeno a mí, el cuál compila y funciona correctamente. Revisando las librerías que se incluyen me he dado cuenta de que existen instrucciones `#define` sin un valor asignado. ¿Es esto posible? Siempre había creído que estas macros sirven para asignar valores numéricos a variables declaradas con letras/palabras para una mejor comprensión a la hora de depurar o entender el código y para que el precompilador asocie dicha constante numérica a una cadena de caracteres.

El código, por ejemplo, quedaría algo así (en este caso `VARIABLE_3` no tiene ningún valor asignado):

```
#define VARIABLE_1     1
#define VARIABLE_2     10
#define VARIABLE_3 
#define VARIABLE_4     200
```

Muchas gracias por la información!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Es esto posible?

Es perfectamente posible.

Las macros son directivas del precompilador, esto es un programa que se ejecuta justo antes que el compilador y cuyo cometido es reemplazar las macros por otra cosa. Así, por ejemplo, los `#include` los reemplaza por el contenido del archivo al que hacen referencia y los símbolos definidos con `#define` se sustituyen por los valores asociados a dichos símbolos.

Los símbolos pueden usarse de varias maneras:

- Se puede comprobar si un símbolo está definido o no. Esto permite personalizar el comportamiento del programa y crear las guardas de las cabeceras

  ```
    #ifdef VARIABLE_3
    // código que se cargará cuando el símbolo esté definido ...
    #else
    // código que se cargará cuando el símbolo no esté definido ...
    #endif
  ```

  Nota que en este caso no se está evaluando en ningún momento el valor asociado al símbolo. Aquí únicamente cuenta si el símbolo ha sido definido o no.
- Un símbolo sin valor asociado no generará código. Esta característica se puede usar para, por ejemplo, tener trazas en debug y no en release:

  ```
    #ifdef DEBUG
    #define LOG(x) std::cout << x << '\n'
    #else
    #define LOG(x)
    #endif

    // ...

    // La macro sólo mostrará valores en la consola cuando el símbolo
    // DEBUG esté definido
    LOG("Mensaje de prueba");
  ```

Comment: Gracias @eferion, me ha quedado muy claro! ;)